# How to allow a Chrome extension to open a site information dialogue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that (among other things) can connect to a serial port specified by the user.
I already found a PWA made using node.js, it makes use of an experimental feature described here: https://wicg.github.io/serial/
I can let node launch a server and connect to it. I run the following code:

```
port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({});
```

Which opens the following dialogue for the user:

[image: Screenshot of working PWA serial port selector]

I'm not sure what the name of this type of dialogue screen is, its connected to the "view site information" icon, so I named it that in the question title. In any case, i'm trying to package this function in a chrome extension, when I run the same code however, the dialogue does not open, immediately returning as if the user had hit "cancel". I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: No port selected by the user.
```

I was thinking maybe this sort of dialogue requires some permission to be enabled in the manifest file. I cannot change the way the port is selected since as far as I understand the relevant code lies in a black box library belonging to google.

Answer (score 0):

USB and Bluetooth are not experimental. The API is supported by Chrome and Edge and have been for a few years. I have built a couple of PWAs using USB.

I am not an extension developer, so not sure of the API is exposed in that context.

There are all sorts of low level programming you need to fuss with for USB and bluetooth for that matter. But its pretty cool once you get it running :)

Also, nodejs has nothing to do with a PWA. That is a server-side platform concern.

Comment: If there is a USB setup that is not experimental could you point me in the right direction? The API I'm using requires me to turn on "experimental features" in both Chrome and Firefox.